# Accessing nested properties in functions via arrays: Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, properties

I can get a first-level property just find, but it won't let me access a 'tint' property under color. Normally you would just use the dot to whichever level you want to reach but it's not working for me.

```
obj = new Object();

obj.color.tint = "brick red";

alert(obj.color);

var arr = [];

arr[0] = obj;

alert(arr[0].color.tint);
```

Comment: This code throws an error. You can check the developer console (Press F12) to debug in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
obj = new Object();

obj.color = new Object(); // Try add this line

obj.color.tint = "brick red";

alert(obj.color);

var arr = [];

arr[0] = obj;

alert(arr[0].color.tint);
```

I am not sure about the statement "*you would just use the dot to whichever level you want to reach*"

Basically Javascript is all about objects, and you can use the dot notation to access an **existing object**.

you can access `obj.color` is because you initialize `obj` as an object at the first place.

So similarily, if you would like to set properties under `obj.color`, you have to initialize `obj.color` as a new object first, then you can access `obj.color.*` at your wish

Answer (score 2):

```
obj.color.tint = "brick red";
```

This part will fail because `color` doesn't exist. JavaScript doesn't "autofill" the gaps. You must define `color` as an object first before assigning `tint` to it.

```
var obj = {};
obj.color = {};
obj.color.tint = 'brick red';
```

Also, this can be simplified to:

```
var obj = {
  color: {
    tint: 'brick red'
  }
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @Shinji-san Note that using `new Object()` is bad practice. It's better to use the object literal `{}` so that you don't get any surprises in case some other code (a library for example) modified the `Object.prototype`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't chain dot-notation to create nested elements, since `color` isn't defined at the point you try to access it's property;

Onw way to do it:

```
var obj = new Object();
obj.color = {};
obj.color.tint = 'tint';
```

Or:

```
var obj = new Object();
obj.color = {tint:'tint'};
```

Comment: Thanks and what if I want to add a prop to tint, wouldn't it be

color.tint = { transparency: 50 }; or obj.color.tint = { transparency: 50 };

All of which would still be objects of 'obj', right?

Comment: @Shinji-san You can nest as long as you like. `obj.my_properties = {visuals:{color:{tint:'red'}}}`

Answer (score 0):

You can not assign properties to a non existent object. First you have to create that object. However sometimes this is a necessity. Let's say you want to have that array object structure dynamically. I had developed an Object method to accomplist that which is `Object.prototype.setNestedValue()` Which works like this

```js
Object.prototype.setNestedValue = function(...a) {
  a.length > 2 ? typeof this[a[0]] === "object" && this[a[0]] !== null ? this[a[0]].setNestedValue(...a.slice(1))
                                                                       : (this[a[0]] = typeof a[1] === "string" ? {} : new Array(a[1]),
                                                                         this[a[0]].setNestedValue(...a.slice(1)))
               : this[a[0]] = a[1];
  return this;
};

var arr = [].setNestedValue(0,"color","tint","brick red");
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
```